# Firebase Sign-In Issue: Page Refresh and Form Breaks

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

I'm encountering an odd issue specifically related to Firebase authentication. When I attempt to sign in, the page refreshes unexpectedly, disrupting the sign-in process. To prevent this, I've used event.preventDefault() within my code, yet the problem persists. Furthermore, altering the button type from "submit" to "button" renders the form unresponsive. Even after simplifying the webpage to contain only the sign-in credentials, the problem persists. It seems that the refresh and form malfunction are somehow tied to the sign-in functionality, despite attempts to isolate the cause. I'm seeking advice or insights on why the sign-in operation triggers a page refresh and breaks the form, even with event.preventDefault() implemented. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
    <form class="login">
        <label for="email">email:</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" />
        <label class="password">password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" />
        <button type="submit">login</button>
    </form>
```

```
const loginForm = document.querySelector(".login");
loginForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault;

    const email = loginForm.email.value;
    const password = loginForm.password.value;

    firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
        .then((cred) => {
            console.log("user logged in", cred.user);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err.message);
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`preventDefault` is a method, so you need to **invoke** is by putting parentheses after it:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

I usually also `return false` at the end of my event handler, which also stops the event from propagating further

Comment: Hi there, I'm still facing the problem even after adding 'e.preventDefault();' in the code. I've reworked the script multiple times, missing it out this time by mistake. But I noticed something strange; when I keep trying to log in, I catch a quick message saying 'Firebase Auth network request failed'.

Comment: Did you also add `return false` at the end of the handler, as I said in my answer?